# Gerrit - Replicating to github?

Tags: git, github, gerrit

Struggling to get gerrit replication working. Here is a sample of my replication.config

```
[remote "github"]
  url = git@github.com:dbousamra/${name}.git
  push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
  push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  timeout = 5
  replicationDelay = 0
  authGroup = Administrators
```

I think I've done it correctly, but when I force a manual gerrit replication I am presented with:

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[2011-07-11 14:43:41,386] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushReplication : Cannot replicate to git@github.com:dbousamra/gitanalysis.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:dbousamra/gitanalysis.git: push not permitted
```

and now

```
ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushReplication : Cannot replicate to git@github.com:dbousamra/All-Projects.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:dbousamra/All-Projects.git: invalid privatekey: /home/git/.ssh/x.pub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with the SSH key and the authentication at Github. Did you create an SSH key for the user, which is running Gerrit and add that SSH key to your Github account?